# After 'resetting the pc' and keeping the personal files, I can't find lots of programs in 'Programs and features'

Tags: windows

I reset my PC recently with the windows function. I choose to keep all the personal files.

Resetting the PC:
[image: resetting the PC]

After resetting, I found that in the 'Programs and features' of the control panel, I can't find lots of programs

Programs and features:
[image: Programs and features]

What should I do now?

Comment: I think its a bit late now.

Comment: When you Reset your system Windows was actually reinstalled. You were warned your applications would have to be reinstalled.

Comment: What you see is entirely normal. Reinstall your Apps.  Download them again if need be.